# Zeppelin web project build error

Tags: node.js, apache-zeppelin

Unable to build the zeppelin code downloaded from GitHub onto to local windows machine. It seems it download 32bit npm all the time.
Is there a way to make it download 64bit npm 
running on win 7 64bit machine

---

```
[INFO] Installing npm version 1.3.8
[INFO] Downloading NPM from http://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.3.8.tgz to E:\software\zep\incubator-zeppelin-master\zeppelin-web\npm.tar.gz
[INFO] Extracting NPM files in node/
[INFO] Unpacking E:\software\zep\incubator-zeppelin-master\zeppelin-web\npm.tar.gz into E:\software\zep\incubator-zeppelin-master\zeppelin-web/node
[INFO] Installed NPM locally.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.23:npm (npm install) on project zeppelin-web: Failed to run task: 'npm in
stall --color=false --proxy=http://***:***@proxy:8080' failed. java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "E:\software\zep\in
cubator-zeppelin-master\zeppelin-web\node\node" (in directory "E:\software\zep\incubator-zeppelin-master\zeppelin-web"): CreateProcess error=216, This
 version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 (3
2-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.23:npm (npm install) on p
roject zeppelin-web: Failed to run task
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Failed to run task
        at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.NpmMojo.execute(NpmMojo.java:62)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
```

Comment: Although I also already have a Latest Node NPM installation on my Win 7 machine

Comment: it worked for me when I used linux centos vm, this downloads 32bit npm by default.

Comment: For me installing node (besides npm on ubuntu 16.04) and running: npm install on the zepplin-web dir helped.